# django cache.set() Type error

Tags: django, python-memcached

I'm using django 1.9 and Python 3. I've installed `python-memcached` and when I try to `cache.set("foo", "bar")` I get this error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Any idea why this is happening? I made sure to set the middleware and add the cache to `settings.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from string/unicode changes in Python 3. In Python 2, string type are bytes, but in Python 3 string type is separate from byte type - which is causing the error you're seeing.

If you're using Python 3.x with memcached, use the `python3-memcached` package. It's a drop in replacement for `python-memcached`.

```
pip install python3-memcached
```